# How to eliminate all the global typings from being accessible from within a module

Tags: typescript

Is there a canonical way to make sure that all the global typings are only available when explicitly requested to be imported?

Say, I am writing a TypeScript module, I installed (for example) jQuery typings, and as soon as I do that, `jQuery`is added to the global space, which I don't want.

The goal here is that any access to such global entities should be explicitly requested via imports first: `import $ from "jquery"`, or something like that.

With single dependincy, like jQuery, this is not a big deal, but when  the amount of dependencies grows, we'd like to control the access to the global space, not to mention that in IDE the code completion is polluted with stuff that we don't need.